# Keeping a bottle of no-rinse sanitiser

Tags: sanitation, equipment, conditioning, cleaning

Some sanitisers, like star-san, chemipro oxi and betadine are no-rinse in certain dilutions. Star-san can additionaly be kept diluted in a bottle for months and used whenever one wishes. Can the same be done with the other two?

Comment: This is a great question.  Too bad there's nobody out there to answer it.

Comment: Oh, c'mon brewchez, there are at least four of us!

Comment: Make that five! :)

Comment: The OP doesn't mention it; Idophor can *not* be kept indefinitely.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Chemipro Oxi I would not consider a sanitizer...cleaner, sure, but it is essentially sodium percarbonate - it technically CAN be used to sanitize, but the amount needed makes it pretty uneconomical.

Betadine, on the other hand, can be used for years...bottles may have an expiration date (typically required on medical-type solutions), but it can be ignored. The rules for use would be the same as StarSan, which is:

Diluted StarSan or Betadine cannot be used indefinitely - it depends on the pH of the solution. For effective sanitizing, you want the pH to be below 5. Homebrew and aquarium stores sell disposable pH test strips, or you can buy a pH meter.

I usually just refill my spray bottle of sanitizer whenever I make up a new batch. If it has been awhile, I test the pH or just make up a fresh bottle. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You can also just add a few drops of StarSan concentrate to your spray bottle to restore the pH of the entire bottle from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Chemipro Oxi can be used as a sanitiser, however it is not listed as one (as far as I have heard) because in Belgium you have to pay special taxes for sanitisers, while cleaners don't have that problem. I contacted brouwland for the above matter, and their response was the following:

> As the Chemipro  oxi  exists out of  peroxides, these would react  with impurities but also turn into  water and oxygen as a normal chemical reaction, if diluted and stored in water.
>
> So your idea is not bad, but will not work well for longer periods up to more than 1 day.

I think this, along with Jim's post, concludes it all.